# how to remove Item in Qtablewidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

My source code ↓

```
ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,7,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(3)));
ui->tableWidget->item(0,7)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

My approach :

delete ui->tableWidget->item(0,7);

If this memory is free?

If not, let me know any other method.

Comment: See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#takeItem

Comment: Deleting the item works just fine. takeItem() is useful if you want to remove the item without deleting (you'll need it at some point though otherwise it will leak).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `setItem(...)` passes ownership of the `QTableWidgetItem` to the `QTableWidget`.

Although `QTableWidgetItem` is not a `QObject`, it does take care to inform the `QTableWidget` about its deletion (from qtablewidget.cpp, Qt 5.1.1):

```
QTableWidgetItem::~QTableWidgetItem()
{
    if (QTableModel *model = (view ? qobject_cast<QTableModel*>(view->model()) : 0))
        model->removeItem(this);
    view = 0;
    delete d;
}
```

`takeItem()` sets the view of the item to `null`, releasing the ownership to the caller.
Because of this, the above code in the item's destructor `model->removeItem(this);` will not be called.

This means that you need to manually delete the `QTableWidgetItem`.
But **it doesn't matter if** you call `takeItem(...)` or not before deleting the item.

See also [Remove QListWidgetItem: QListWidget::takeItem(item) vs delete item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44783228/399908).

Comment: my Qt ver 4.8...can't using

Comment: Sure? Does the QTableWidgetItem destructor code look different in your Qt version's qtablewidget.cpp file?

Comment: QTableModel is no more available in Qt 5

Comment: @sonulohani `QTableModel` exists, but it doesn't belong to the public API.
The code in my answer is from the Qt 5.6.1 source file `QTableWidget.cpp`, line 1344. It just shows how internally the `QTableWidgetItem` will inform the model of its deletion, so you can simply `delete itm` without `widget->takeItem(itm)` first.

Comment: @MartinHennings Thanks for the clarification. Got it.